# Data not load to UITableView with Alamofire + SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

In my iOS app I'm using Alamofire for rest request and SwiftyJSON for parsing. the rest url is working and I get all data from server, I print it in console. but I can't populate that data with UITableView. I get no errors, project compiles and runs without any issue, but the table view is empty. this is my simple code:

```
var contracts = [Contract]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getContracts(contractSearchCriteria: ContractSearchCriteria())

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (contracts.count != 0) {
        return contracts.count
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contractCell", for: indexPath)

    let contract = self.contracts[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = contract.insuredPersonFullName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contract.companyName

    return cell
}
```

this is **getContracts** method:

```
func getContracts(contractSearchCriteria : ContractSearchCriteria) {
    let params : Parameters = ["insuredPersonName": contractSearchCriteria.insuredPersonName]

    Alamofire.request("\(Constants.restURL)getContracts", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in

        switch (response.result) {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let result = Result(json: json)
            print(result.isSuccess)

            for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
                print(data)
                self.contracts.append(Contract(json: data))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }


    })

}
```

I use swift 3, and latest Alamofire with SwiftyJSON in Xcode 8. what is wrong in my code? I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```